# Android ICS Skin for our applications

Tags: android, skinning

Is there a easy way to have our application look like ICS or JB?
Mainly the slider and the radio button. They look old when displayed in green.

Any hint about this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice package available on [github](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) called HoloEverywhere.

One thing though, do not try pass it off as a ICS/JB Application, just because it "*looks*" like the user interface one would expect to see in a native ICS/JB Android set up.

Best that can be done with the project, is to target the latest SDK to guarantee your wide-market of Android usage, including GB.

Aim high, not low ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the Android Library '[Actionbar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)'. This Library uses all native ICS Themes, etc for older devices.

> ActionBarSherlock is an extension of the compatibility library designed to facilitate the use of the action bar design pattern across all versions of Android with a single API.